# $\epsilon$-$\delta$ definition about the limit, is possible to change $\forall \epsilon>0$ to $\exists\epsilon>0$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, limits

> [image]

click for [link](https://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/classes/calcI/defnoflimit.aspx)

What would happen if $\forall\epsilon>0$ in the definition change into $\exists\epsilon>0$. Why is it not correct?

Comment: Then it works only for that $\epsilon$. For example, $\epsilon=10^{10}$ would satisfy this new definition in most of the cases without a problem and for many $L$s.

Comment: I don't understand your question... consider the function $\operatorname{sgn}(x)=\begin{cases}1&\text{if }x>0\\0&\text{if }x=0\\ -1&\text{if }x<0\end{cases}$.  You can look at the graph... it is very clearly discontinuous at $0$.  Despite this every output of the function is within $3$ of eachother... as every output is either $-1,0,$ or $1$.  Changing it to $\exists$ clearly does not have the same meaning as when it were $\forall$.

Comment: Any function that is bounded near $a$ would satisfy the definition. It is too inclusive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the function which is $0$ for $x\le 0$ and $1$ for $x>0$.

The function is continuous at $0$ if you replace for all with there exists in the definition .

However it is not continuous in the usual definition at $0$.

It might help to analyse this picture to understand why the definition is the way it is.[From the brilliant website on epsilon delta continuity ]
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Because it's possible that for some choice of $\epsilon$, the inequality
$|f(x)-L|<\epsilon$ is **always** true no matter what $x$ is, regardless of whether or not $f$ is continuous.

Concrete example: Suppose $f$ is bounded by $M>0$ (i.e., $-M\leq f(x)\leq M$), and set $\epsilon = 1 + M + |L|$.

Then

$$|f(x)-L| \leq|f(x)| + |L| \leq M+|L| < 1 + M + |L| = \epsilon$$
so
$$|f(x)-L| < \epsilon$$
for all $x$, and in particular for $0<|x-a|<\delta$.

The real problem is to ensure that **no matter how small $\epsilon$ is**, you can always find a $\delta$ that makes the implication hold. Large values of $\epsilon$ aren't the problem--it's the small values that are hard.

Answer (score 1):

If by $P(f,a,L)$ you mean the predicate $$[\exists \varepsilon >0,\exists \delta >0,\forall x, (0<\lvert x-a\rvert<\delta\to \lvert f(x)-L\rvert<\varepsilon)]$$

Then, given any $f:\Bbb R\to\Bbb R$ and any $a, L\in\Bbb R$, the property $P(f,a,L)$ is true if and only if there is a neighbourhood $U\ni a$ such that $f$ is bounded on $U$.

This isn't, of course, the case for $$Q(f,a,L)\equiv[\forall \varepsilon>0,\exists\delta>0,\forall x,(0<\lvert x-a\rvert<\delta\to \lvert f(x)-L\rvert<\varepsilon)]$$

which is a more demanding condition on $f$ and $L$.